# JQuery UI Draggable on long press works with mousedown but not touchstart

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, touch, touch-event

The following works fine on desktop (`mousedown`) but if you try it on mobile (`touchstart`) it doesn't drag.

```js
var t;
$(document).on('touchstart mousedown','.menu-item', function (event) {
  var self = this;
  if ($(self).hasClass('draggable')) return;
  t = setTimeout(function () {
    $(self).draggable({
      revert: true,
      appendTo: 'body'
    }).draggable('enable').addClass('draggable');
    $(self).trigger(event)
  }, 800);
});

$(document).on("touchend mouseup", function () {
  clearTimeout(t);
  $('.draggable').draggable( 'disable' ).removeClass('draggable');
});
```

```css
.menu-item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
}
.menu-item.draggable {
  background-color: orange;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item">1</div>
<div class="menu-item">2</div>
<div class="menu-item">3</div>
```

How can I make it work with both?

Comment: You may want to use TouchPunch.

Comment: Look here : http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Yes, it does seem to work with Touchpunch.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it works, may also look at `$(self).trigger(event)`, docs suggest this shoudl be jQuery.Event object. May need `$(self).trigger(event.type);` instead... not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing jquerymobile with [touchpunch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) fixed the problem, no code changes required.